# Google Analytics hash

Tags: hash, google-analytics

I am using folowing code to track haschanges in googleanalytics:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
  ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': location.pathname + location.hash});
})
```

It works but it sends also the parameters following the hashtag.

if the URL maybe looks like

> www.example.de/somepage/#myhashtag?parm1=this&param2=that&param3=foo

The tracked URL in Analytics looks like

> somepage/#myhashtag?parm1=this&param2=that&param3=foo

but I want

> somepage/#myhashtag

What I am doing wrong? :)

Comment: {'page':'' + location.hash});

Comment: I needed to explain it better, because if I have a page before, of course I want to see this as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong; that's the way location.hash works. You could try this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': location.pathname + location.hash.split("?")[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

{'page': + window.location.hash}); // or "/" +  window.location.hash
I see, try to substring only hash, using hash.lenght then substring from path etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out another option is to tell Analytics in the properties to ignore specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @nyuen said, If you're trying to track this site as a single page app, you should read the [developer guide for tracking single page applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications).

There are several gotchas when it comes to what you're trying to do, so that link will probably be helpful. For example, they way you're doing it now. If you were to send an event later, it would be associated with the wrong page because you're not updating the tracker object when the hash changes.